# Install a windows VM on my CentOS server

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, centos, vps

I have a dedicated server with a centOS installed. I need a windows environment. I just thought if it would be possible to install a Windows virtual machine and use remote desktop to connect to it.

I want to know if that is possible (which I feel positive about it!) and How should I do the process? What should I need to learn and what possible tools can I use? Should I setup a VPS for it?

Sorry If the question seems stupid! I am not for sure.

Comment: Yes install a virtualization tool and the install windows in it

Comment: This is rather broad, but if you narrow your question down to one aspect/issue, we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

i've used xen hypervisor type 1 and 2 successfully.
prefer type 1. but sounds like you're gonna need type 2.  From what I've read, rpm based distros are getting, or should have, xen support now.  I know openSuSE has it, I use Debian on one test machine and citrix xenserver on another. create your virtual switch appropriately and you should be golden.